# Create regex for loop that searches every string in a list against a document

Tags: python, regex, for-loop

Apologies for my lack of knowledge, but I'm trying to figure out how to create a regex for loop that would search the value of each string in `lst_a` against a document. If there are matches I was hoping to get the output to be `True/False` for each string.

**For example:**

```
lst_a = ['Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet', 'consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.', 'Ut enim ad minim veniam']
doc = doc.txt
```

**Example Output:**

```
[True False False]
```

**My attempt:**

```
import re

  lst_a = ['Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet', 'consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.', 'Ut enim ad minim veniam']

for i in lst_a:
    re_pattern = r'lst_a[i]'
    regex = re.compile(re_pattern)

with open('doc.txt') as doc:
    for line in doc:
        match = regex.search(line)
```

Comment: Are you trying to optimize, for instance only check each line once for the strings in the list ?

Comment: I am only trying to check each string once, but I was hoping to use a regex function because the text in doc.txt may be slightly off (e,g, capitalization and punctuation). So I thought if I could iteratively create a regex function I could preform a "like" search similar to MySQL.

Comment: The document is big ? Then you want to iterate _it_ only once. The problem stems from mapping which string matched.

Answer (score 1):

If you are just looking for a string in a document, you do not need to use a regular expression. According to your problem description, you want to know if a string exists in a document. Yet your code seems to be trying to match line by line, which is not what you should be doing if you problem description is accurate.

```
lst_a = ['Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet', 'consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.', 'Ut enim ad minim veniam']

with open('doc.txt') as doc:
    document_text = doc.read()
# a list comprehension:
matches = [string in document_text for string in lst_a]
"""
The above is equivalent to:
matches = []
for string in lst_a:
    # test if string occurs anywhere in document_text and return True or False
    matches.append(string in document_text)
"""
```

`matches` will be a list such as `[True, False, True]`